# Monterey getting localhost to connect error

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf, macos-monterey

Just updated to Monterey and getting localhost to connect gives this error:

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Following excellent guides with brew I have  installed httpd
And running this command in MacOS Terminal

```
brew services restart httpd
```

returns

```
==>Successfully stopped `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
==> Successfully started `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
```

but then connecting to: http://localhost:8080/ gives the error above
thank you

Comment: are you sure that port 8080 is the correct one? I'd rather expect 80 as default, and you don't give an indication that you're configuring Apache httpd any way other than the default.

Comment: thank you @ Olaf Kock - you made me check - having tried both several times - and yes it is :80 and it is working (embarrasing)   - thank you
If you would kindly post port 80 as the answer I will confirm it ...

Comment: I have the same problem. Currently I'm looking into a missing self signing authority problem that I have.
Run `apachectl configtest`
Do you get `AH06665: No code signing authority for module at /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so specified in LoadModule directive.`?

Comment: Running apachectl configtest I get "syntax OK"
Try "which httpd" and see directory it is pointing to (see partial answer below).  My guess is that the code signing is related to Apple's version of Apache.  
The link below delineates both options with a link to Code Signing.  https://wpbeaches.com/updating-to-php-versions-7-4-and-8-on-macos-12-monterey/

As an alternative to Code Signing and using Apples in-built Apache, you may want instead to use both Apache and PHP from Homebrew - see  https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: careful editing of httpd.conf a complete reinstall of brew and computer restart at key moments has helped and it is now serving up http:localhost fine - the next issue is that any php file is not rendering so  a link to http:localhost/success.php returns "<?php echo 'Success' ; ?>" in the browser instead of "Success"

Answer (score 2):

I add this in case it helps someone...
The real issue was that all of the move from Apple provided Apache to Apache installed by brew was not complete and so page only showed if Moneterey Apache was running
Simple solution was to complete configuration of httpd file and restart Mac ~ then all fell in to line:
To test the location of Apache/httpd from Terminal run:

```
which httpd
```

Homebrew location is:

> /usr/local/bin/httpd

If you are getting the default macOS location of

> /usr/sbin/httpd

Restart the computer and try the location test again.
My thanks to [WP Beaches](https://wpbeaches.com/installing-configuring-apache-on-macos-using-homebrew/) for this

More experimentation - it seems that I have to restart OS Monterey everytime I change httpd.conf   A simple Brew restart httpd doesn't appear to reload the configuration

Final insight - using the brew suggested links to phpmyadmin results in a 404 error - without the brew alias as below - it works fine:

```
    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
<   Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not realise that Apple's apache is the problem. I used the tutorial you linked there and now I'm up and running again. With apache from homebrew. (I feard to have to do a rollback to Big Sur)
Cheers!

Comment: Now installed php, mariadb (mysql is not valid for Monterey) and phpmyadmin
However adding the configurations for phpmyadmin, that Brew suggests, to httpd.conf creates the original error of "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect" ~ any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You give no indication that you're changing httpd's ports anywhere, yet you're trying to connect to 8080 - I'd not expect anyone to answer there. Port 80 (the default for http), e.g. `http://localhost/` would be a more sensible address to expect an answer on.

Comment: Thank you @Olaf - this is certainly part of the answer - but I still have the issue - even after a reboot and restart of httpd - expect it is the httpd.conf settings.  I will update as soon as I discover what it is.

Comment: your yesterday's comment sounded like this solved your problem...

Comment: it did briefly but after a restart it was not connecting with the same error message

Comment: Now sorted - please see my answer and also the comments on @nsdb answer

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 works for mine case.OS Monetery m1 mac mini.

Comment: Also " sudo launchctl bootout system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist "